External Credentials - implement custom auth scheme
To authenticate in an external services, I have to run this requests :
curl 'https://SERVICE_URL/v2/authenticate' \
    -X POST \
    -H 'Bridge-Version: 2021-06-01' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \  
    -H 'Client-Id: MY_CLIENT_ID' \
    -H 'Client-Secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -d $'{
        "user_uuid": "f2a8c758-bcc9-4a9c-9162-5aac16932d99"

Which gives ACCESS_TOKEN and then, to get info from the end point :
curl 'https://SERVICE_URL/v2/items/' 
-X GET 
-H 'Bridge-Version: 2021-06-01' 
-H 'Client-Id: MY_CLIENT_ID' 
-H 'Client-Secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Can you correct my Salesforce set up ? I did :
A/ Set up a oAuth2 External credential with Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow.

URL : https://SERVICE_URL/v2/authenticate
Set up a Principal with client-id and client-secret
Set up custom headers

Set up a permission set to access this Principal
Set up a Named Credential with Allo Formula in Headers and body and this custom header


Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I get the error when I try to connect to the API to get the schema

Is someone can advice to be able to make it work ? Some ideas :

in the external credential, is the header of oAuth to restrictive (spelling of "Client-Id" or "Client-Secret" ?
in the external credential, I tried to set it up to Custom but I don't know how to set up different endpoint to authenticate
In the named credential, may I need to set up custom headers to pass client-id and client-secret. If so, How can i get with merge field the values

Thank you for your help

This isn't oAuth, it's some proprietary scheme. You can use external cred with custom auth scheme to vault your secrets but that's all you'll be able to do with EC. The bulk of this will have to be coded in Apex. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_custom_auth_ext_cred.htm&type=5
